# ws.Range(x).value as double type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a code that looks like this:

```
Dim x As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("1")

x= ws.Range("namedcell").Value
MsgBox (x)
```

The named cell contains value like 5.05, where later I want to use it to calculations so it should be double. Like:

```
newx = x * 1.05
```

I can msgbox it when I use x as string, but not as integer or double.

help?

Comment: Change the `5.05` to `5,05`?

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: .... srsly, oh ghad im not thinking today.... Thanks.




it was because cell had 5.05 not 5,05